# How do I send an NServiceBus message when a file is created?

Tags: nservicebus, filesystemwatcher

I know how to use the `FileSystemWatcher` class, and I know how to send the message I want to send. What I can't figure out is where to initialize the `FileSystemWatcher`.

I'm assuming that there's some place to initialize an `Endpoint` where I could set this up, but I'm not certain where that would be.

Seems like this would be a common use-case; I'm a little surprised that Udi hasn't built this into NServiceBus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is built into NServiceBus.

You need to implement a class that derives from `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops`.
See http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/the-nservicebus-host#custom-initialization-and-startup for more info.

Comment: Thanks, John... but the use-case I was referring to is "Generate Message on File Creation". I suppose since is trivial to do (if you know which interface to implement) that it's just not compelling enough to make a part of the product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try the following and tell you if it worked:

1. Create a FileWatcher class with

a. a static boolean variable 'keepChecking'

b. a static method watchFiles() which initiates the FileSystemWatcher and then stays alive with a loop that tests the keepChecking

b. the OnChange etc. FileSystemWatcher event handlers 
- which upon being triggered by the FileSystemWatcher, presumably send out NServiceBus events

2. To start the watcher (in my NSB Host program) You run the WatchFiles() method in a separate thread in a starter class which inherits from IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops.
3. To stop the watcher you first set the watcher.EnableRaisingEvents to false then set the keepWatching to false so the loop ends.

A similar approach in this StackOverflow question with code: 
[NServicebus with File System Watcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170342/nservicebus-with-file-system-watcher) from Tylor Day.

Except that he unified the starter class with the filewatcher class and its (non-static) creation method running in the same thread. Interestingly it works without the need for a keepalive loop, since the FileSystemWatcher event-subscription is defined as static.

He was told that this is not the best way to go and was given two suggestions: a. To use a "satellite class" or b. To move the whole thing to a separate class, making the fileWatcher itself static. No mention of a keepalive loop. I'll try that too.