# NServicebus with File System Watcher

Tags: c#, nservicebus, filesystemwatcher

I want my endpoint to send out an event whenever a detects a file in a specific folder is dropped.  I was able to get it to work by using a class which implements IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops, which in turn sets up a FileSystemWatcher to monitor the given folder.  My questions is, is this the best way to go about this with nservicebus or am I missing something that may cause me trouble down the line?

Here is my code:

```
public class FileSystem : IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
{
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher;

    public void Start()
    {
        ConfigFileWatcher();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private void ConfigFileWatcher()
    {
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"c:\";
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    // Define the event handlers. 
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

        // fire off an event here...
    }
```

}

Comment: What's your question/concern exactly?

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering if there is better way of doing this and/or are there any performance issues with this approach?  Is the IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops interface even intended to be used like this?

Comment: Have you tested it to work? Doesn't it get disposed after the bus has started?

Comment: Yes, it does work and it continues to work even after the bus has started.  I also thought it would have been disposed of.  That's why I am unsure of whether this is the right way to go, since something about it feels "wrong" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the NServiceBus source code, in the container initialization, you will see that IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops is registered with the life cycle of one per call

```
ForAllTypes<IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops>(TypesToScan, t => configurer.ConfigureComponent(t, DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall));
```

This means that the class will be disposed after Start() is called. Your implementation works because your events are subscribed to a static handler, which keeps subscriptions alive.

We use file watchers in production but we bake them as advanced satellites. Satellites are guaranteed to be initialized as singletons and will not be disposed. They have Start and Stop methods as well. They do have addresses and should be able to handle incoming messages but you can use some dummy address and do nothing in the handler unless you want to make your file system watcher satellite bidirectional (ie receive messages and put them as files on the disk).

In NServiceBus it is **recommended** to make constantly running, non-disposable processes as satellites. Many NServiceBus components are made as satellites.

You might get curious how to make a satellite yourself, but it is quite easy to do. You can check the interface signature [here](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/b7c14898eb5875edb5f889542e50cb2cd9c6dc73/src/NServiceBus.Core/Satellites/ISatellite.cs).

It will look something like this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using NServiceBus;
using NServiceBus.Satellites;

public class FileSystem : ISatellite
{
    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    public bool Handle(TransportMessage message)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = @"c:\",
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess |    NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
            Filter = "*.txt"
        };
        _watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        _watcher.Created += OnChanged;
        _watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _watcher.Dispose();
    }

    public Address InputAddress
    {
        get { return Address.Parse("FileSystemSatellite"); }
    }

    public bool Disabled
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    // Define the event handlers. 
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or    deleted.
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

        // fire off an event here...
    }
}
```

There one thing you need to remember: each satellite gets its own queue. In this case it will always be empty.

Comment: That makes sense, but strangely the File Watcher events continue to fire even after Start() is called.  Maybe this watcher resource is keeping the object from being disposed of?  Do you have any documentation for satellites?  I am using version 5.0 if that helps.

Comment: As Phil mentioned in his answer, because your event handler is a static method, subscriptions are not disposed and the watcher is kept alive by GC. I edited my answer with this comment and added a sample satellite implementation,

Comment: What will cause the satellite class to start?  I made a project with the NServiceBus.Host from Nuget (using RavenDB persistence). 

When I ran a static FileSystemWatcher  from a class with IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops it ran ok and gave the file changing events. 

But when I changed that to work according to Alexy's example with a non-static FileSystemWatcher in a class that implements ISatellite  the Start() method is never called. 

Is there something further I need to do?

Comment: I do not use their internal container API but with Autofac you would need to register it with .AsImplementedInterfaces() for the consumer to be able to resolve it as an ISatellite

Comment: After talking with Hadi from the NServiceBus support, it turns out all I had to do was set the Disabled parameter-get to return false.

There was no need for the configuration line at all (although it worked).  The satellite works "out of the box".

Comment: It works OK and catches the files without being static. Now the problem is this: Why is the IBus property I added to the satellite file not being automatically populated? Is there something more I have to do? Add an IBus param to the constructor and save it during construction?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the other answer and comments, I believe your FileSystemWatcher is being kept alive by its subscription to the OnChanged event.

This is actually a (fairly) common cause of memory leaks, though in your case it actually keeps your watcher in memory and allows it to continue operating.  Remove the static keyword from your OnChanged() method, and I believe you will see the behavior that you would expect.

Of course, you *want* the FileSystemWatcher to keep functioning . . . one option might be to just make the watcher variable static itself.  If you go that route, I would put it in a separate class, and just initialize it via the class that implements IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops.

Comment: But what will keep it alive?  

If the Runner:IWantToRun...  class dies wont the static FileWatcher.watcher variable die along with it? 

Or are you saying that in the new FileWatcher class to make both the OnChanged and the watcher variables static?  (In which case, as is happening now, the watcher is kept alive...)

Comment: If it's static, it will stay alive even after the class goes out of scope or is disposed.